# Replication and expansion of program flags in BASH script

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

I am working with a program that combines individuals files, and I am incorporating this program into a BASH pipeline that I'm putting together. The program requires a flag for each file, like so:

```
program -V file_1.g.vcf -V file_2.g.vcf -V file_3.g.vcf -O combined_output.g.vcf
```

In order to allow the script to work with any number of samples, I would like to read the individual files names within a directory, and expand the path for each file after a '-V' flag.

I have tried adding the file paths to a variable with the following, but have not had success with proper expansion:

```
GVCFS=('-V' `ls gvcfs/*.g.vcf`)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using a loop to populate an array with the options:

```
options=()
for file in gvcfs/*.g.vcf; do    # Don't parse ls, just use a direct wildcard expression
    options+=(-V "${file##*/}")    # If you want the full path, leave off ##*/
done

program "${options[@]}" -O combined_output.g.vcf
```

Answer (score 0):

`printf` can help:

```
options=( $(printf -- "-V %s " gvcfs/*.g.vcf ) )
```

Though this will not deal gracefully with whitespace in filenames.
Also consider `realpath` to generate absolute filenames.

Comment: Does the output of `declare -p options` look correct?

Comment: You need a space before `-V` (or after the `%s`) otherwise you'll get "filename-V" as many of the array elements. (What Cyrus said). Plus the whitespace thing.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. I had tested it with \n in the format string, and then removed that while writing the answer, without trying again.